# Decompressing archive to a single folder

Tags: zip, archive

Maybe this is the pinnacle of first world problems, but after years of angst I just have to air this.

Let's say you have downloaded `funtool.zip` in your `~/Downloads` folder. You have two choices, each with two possible outcomes, depending on whether the archive has a proper root folder.

`unzip funtool`. Possible outcomes:

- `~/Downloads/funtool/(files)` -- Good
- `~/Downloads/(lots of files)` -- AUGH! Download folder littered

`unzip funtool -d funtool`. Possible outcomes:

- `~/Downloads/funtool/funtool/(files)` -- Double folders. Annoying!
- `~/Downloads/funtool/(files)` -- Good

I've seen some GUI decompressors have built-in intelligence for this, but I'm a CLI guy. My solution is to check for a root folder by `unzip -t funtool` and act accordingly. But after years, I've had it.

Is there a script or something that does this automatically, even for `rar` files, and possibly `7z`? At least this is one thing that `tar` seems to get right every time, maybe because of good conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a CLI frontend to various archive formats, there is `unp`, *unpack (almost) everything with one command*.

And it claims to have these options:

```
   -u Special helper mode.
      For most archive types:
      - create directory <filename without suffix>/
      - extract contents there
      For Debian/Ubuntu packages:
      - extract data.tar.gz after each operation in local directory
      - extract control.tar.gz into control/<package_version_arch>/
   -U Smart mode, acts like -u (see above) if archive contains multiple
      elements but if there is only one file/directory element then it's stored 
      in the current directory.
```

And that *sounds* like it's close to the behavior you are looking for.

However the `-U` mode still litters a single file if it's a ZIP with a single file that is not related in any way whatsoever to the name of the zipfile itself.

Comment: Yes! The `-U` switch seems to do it right. This goes to show once more there's always at least one more person on the planet who shares your hangups.

Answer (score 0):

`7z` can do this, at least if the root directory in the archive (if any) matches the name of the directory you’re extracting to:

```
7z x -spe funtool.zip -ofuntool
```

If `funtool.zip`’s contents are all inside a `funtool` directory in the archive, `7z` won’t duplicate the directory below `funtool`, giving you the result you’re after.

Comment: That brings you back to having to list the archive to get that name. It should be smarter about it: If there is a root folder, use that. If not, use the archive base name. And it should do it by default, so you can just do `7z x funtool.zip`. Well, there's always aliases...

Answer (score 0):

There's the command line tool [dtrx](https://brettcsmith.org/2007/dtrx/), which is able to extract any sort of compressed file. By default, everything will be written to a dedicated directory that's named after the archive.

Simply run

```
dtrx <archive_name>
```

If you have a Debian-based distribution you can find it in the APT repository.

Comment: Does it create the directory even if the archive has its own root directory?